# Eventsource API : EXCEPTION: No activity within 300000 milliseconds. Reconnecting

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events, polyfills, server-push, eventsource

I am using eventSource API and added the addEventListener() to the eventsouce. The event source is activated till only 45 seconds. I want to keep the connection alive until the server send the response back to client.

Now, I am getting the below exception because there is no response back from the server till 45 secs.

**EXCEPTION: No activity within 300000 milliseconds. Reconnecting.**

Please give me some pointers to make the connection alive/ any other approach to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to send data periodically, even null bytes work and will keep the connection alive.

If the connection can not be established and you want to retry connecting, it is possible to use `setTimeout` set for instance to 45 seconds.

Once the connection is established use `clearTimeout` to stop trying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

Yes... I can avoid the error and can also be handled it. I also tried to repeat the request to establish the connection but still No success. 

Do you have any idea how to use retry in eventsource so that it would be automatically retrying to establish the connection?

Comment: Can you try a simple setTimeout (and once the connection is set up clearTimeout), to see if this works? If it does we can find a more elegant solution

Comment: You are welcome. I will now edit my answer accordingly. (And done)

Answer (score 2):

> I using EventSourcePolyfill and I managed to extend the time from 45000 milliseconds to 2 minutes using heartbeatTimeout: 120000,

```
const sse = new EventSourcePolyfill(`yourURL`,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
                            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                            'X-Accel-Buffering': 'no',
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                        },
                        heartbeatTimeout: 120000,
                        withCredentials: true,
                    });
    
                        sse.onmessage = (e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                        sse.onerror = (event) => {
                            console.log(event);
                            sse.close();
                        }
```